# Can't tap a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I have a tap button in the input system, but when I try to tap the button of it, it doesn't call the action

```
public void OnCrouchUncrouchUnPhrone(InputValue value)
{
    if(value.isPressed)
        {
            Debug.Log("pressed")
```

but when I try to call it, doesnt work. I have other input actions with the same code but they work.

Here is the image of the non-working binding:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGzkZ.png)

And here is the image of a random working binding:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXofR.png)

And here is the image of the player input:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFYK.png)

Now, the reason I want it tap instead of the default one that works, is because there is another with the same binding but it just detects whether the button is held and I want the script to detect either one of those, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**solution** : remove `if(value.isPressed)` dont check for isPressed.

**Reason** : most common reason will be the check for isPressed . as Tap is getting called when you press and release, so isPressed will always be false as the method is getting called only after release.

Comment: Just to back this with the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html#tap): `A TapInteraction requires the user to press and release a Control within duration seconds to trigger the Action.` => As said here at the moment the action is triggered the button will not be pressed anymore

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot, I didn't that you could remove ```if(value.isPressed)```, I though that it was required to check if the input was being called